# How to solve this "4th dimension" missing certificate problem?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a rest client maven module which is responsible for getting a token, and then for creating requests using this token.

Here is the "login()" method :

```
  private static final String ROOT_URL = "https://my-url";
  private static final String LOGIN_API = "/LogIn";

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myRestTemplate")
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public String login() {
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    loginRequest.setAccountName("USER");
    loginRequest.setPassword("P@ssw0rd");
    loginRequest.setTimeout(120);

    LoginResponse loginResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(ROOT_URL + LOGIN_API, loginRequest, LoginResponse.class);
    String token = loginResponse.getLogInResult().getToken();

    log.info(loginResponse.toString());
    return token;
  }
```

When I call this "login()" method from a JUnit inside the module, it works.

Also I have various services from other modules who depend on this rest client module and they can call it with no error.

Now I've just created a new module who needs to use this rest client service. When I call the "login()" service from this new module, it ends with :

```
ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://my-url/LogIn": 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What can possibly could cause this error in a case and not the other, when the URL called is a constant ?

I've tried to check the "restTemplate" object is the same in both case and I think it is, but even if it was not, how could this happen ? by which mechanism ?

UPDATE : I've tried to activate spring debug on org.springframework.beans to see if a wrong restTemplate injection could be the cause of this problem, but when I do this from my parent module, I don't even see the injection of any restTemplate.

It's like some process are happening in a forked JVM, and this forked process doesnt know about the certificates (the ones in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts).

If I debug the call from the child module, I can see the restTemplate injection happening.

Comment: I guess that in your module you don't have a valid truststore where to find a valid root CA. Are you using the same JDK/JRE used for the unit test?

Comment: Module don't own truststore. Same IDE (eclipse), same way of launching JUnit with no specific parameters (created using Alt + shift + x then t), same JDK.